# How do i pair my AirPods to my iPhone 6s?

Tags: iphone, airpods

How do I pair my AirPods to my phone? I have tried everything, such as turning off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. Contacting Apple Support did not help.

Comment: What did you do?  What did Apple Support advise you that ultimately failed?

Comment: I just got them yesterday, and am paring them for the first time. Apple Support did not know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will open up your iPhone (i.e. use TouchID/FaceID/PIN-code) and bring it to the Home Screen (i.e. where you can see all the icons for you apps). Then bring the AirPods case near the iPhone and open it up.

After a short wait, a popup message will appear on your phone asking if you want to setup the new set of AirPods.

If that isn't working, check that:

- The AirPods case is charged
- WiFi and Bluetooth are not disabled on your phone
- Your phone is updated with the latest iOS updates

If that is still not working then try opening the lid, wait 20 seconds, and then hold the setup button on the back of the case, until the status light begins to flash white. Now check with your phone - perhaps even from the Settings app to check for Bluetooth devices nearby in pairing mode.